# How to maximize performance for desktop WPF app used to review a set of images and videos on the local machine

Tags: c#, wpf, image, video, desktop-application

I'm creating a desktop WPF app on Win 10 x64 with VS 2017.  I have a set of images and videos (.mp4 and .avi) in a directory structure.  The app will allow the user to flip through the images and videos to review them.

The basic idea is to recursively find all supported image and video files and then show the first one.  The user will then index forward and backwards through the set and it will show each one.  For videos, it will play the video.  Ideally, the user would be able to "skim" through displayed videos making it quicker to review them as opposed to watching them in real time.

I tried this initially using the WPF MediaElement control and it didn't perform as well as I would have hoped.  I created a single MediaElement control in the window and then as the user indexed through the files, I set the Source property for each one.

- There was a noticeable delay when switching to the next/prev item.  Having this delay reduces the useability when trying to review a large number of files and then quickly go back and forth between a few.
- I could not find a way to pre-load media and then have the control immediately switch to and display the loaded media.  I think if this was possible it may make the switching faster.  The idea would be to pre-load N files before and N files after the current one and maintain those preloaded files so that switching feels much more responsive
- The MediaElement control crashed on some AVI files I fed it
- I couldn't see an easy way to add a skimming control so that, for videos, the user could quickly skim around the video and not watch the entire thing in real time
- I tried creating a series of MediaElement controls and showing/collapsing them (to attempt a pre-load) but this didn't seem to help and felt pretty hacky anyway :)

Having done this experimentation, I'm wondering if anyone else out there may have advice from their experience as to a better approach?  Would you suggest a third party control?  Am I just not using MediaElement correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to pre-load multiple media elements into a **single** control which won't do anything for latency, why not have multiple hidden controls that are each pre-loaded for a particular image or video in the background. When advancing to the next clip merely show that control and hide the other?

e.g.

Control **A** - to load prior media element; **hidden**

Control **B** - shows current media; visible

Control **C** - to load next media; **hidden**

WPF layout:

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
```

Whilst the user is staring at the current media, have controls **A** and **C** load respective images or videos.

Now if the user clicks **Next**, make Control **C** visible and hide **B**.  **B** and **C** essentally become swapped visually.   Have **B** load the next image/video.

Though it may not guarentee that the video or image is ready for viewing when advancing, it should cut down on the latency.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, that was one of the things I tried.  It didn't seem to help with the latency when switching to the next/prev media file.  After experimentation, I began thinking MediaElement may not be the best approach.  So I thought I'd see if anyone else had experience with a similar problem and figured it out.

Comment: @Nerdtron there are many ways to skin a cat.  Perhaps it was just the way you tried? :)

Comment: very true :)  hopefully I can find a way to get something workable.